# I'm trying to update the data in table column "Supplier_Base.CreditBalance" with the sum of the colum "Purch" in table "Suppliers_Account"

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net-2010

This was what i'm trying but it does not work.

```
UPDATE
    dbo.Supplier_Base SET dbo.Supplier_Base.CreditBalance (
SELECT     
    SUM(dbo.Suppliers_Account.Purch ) AS BAL,
FROM         
    dbo.Suppliers_Account 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Supplier_Base ON dbo.Suppliers_Account.Code = dbo.Supplier_Base.Code
GROUP BY dbo.Suppliers_Account.Code, dbo.Supplier_Base.CreditBalance
HAVING      (dbo.Suppliers_Account.Code = N'C003'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax:

```
UPDATE SB
SET CreditBalance = SA.Purch
FROM dbo.Supplier_Base SB
INNER JOIN (SELECT Code, SUM(Purch) Purch
            FROM  dbo.Suppliers_Account)
            GROUP BY Code) SA
    ON SB.Code = SA.Code
WHERE SB.Code = N'C003'
```

Comment: You missed the constraint for `SA.Code = N'C003'`

Comment: @Cory Yup, didn't even realize there was a filter, but is easily implemented

Answer (score 0):

Sub-queries aren't allowed in a SET statement. You can work around this by aliasing the tables and doing a `JOIN` instead.

Do you have a test environment where you can run queries with damaging production data? I think this is what you're looking for, but DO test it first:

```
UPDATE
    b
SET
    b.CreditBalance = SUM(a.Purch)
FROM         
    dbo.Suppliers_Account a
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Supplier_Base b
    ON 
    a.Code = b.Code
WHERE   
    a.Code = N'C003'
GROUP BY 
    a.Code
```